# How to reset the network setting in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: network-manager

How to Reset my network setting in Ubuntu 18.04

Because currently, I'm not able to start my system WiFi-hotspot.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not able to start my system WiFi-hotspot". Specifically, How (and with what apps) did you configure it in the first place? Was it working before? Did you change anything? How are you trying to start it? Do you get any error messages? The more detail the easier it is to help you. Please update the question with this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

To view **status** of the **Network Manager Service**:

```
$ systemctl status network-manager.service
```

To **restart** the **Network Manager Service**:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

Comment: Restarting NetworkManager does not achieve what people often think, and is usually wrong to do. In particular, when restarting NetworkManager it will try hard not to change the network configuration, so that you can restart the service without disconnecting yourself. The only reason to restart the daemon is if you update the package or change some options in `NetworkManager.conf` (many options can be reloaded without restart).

Comment: Hotspot is not detecting in other devices. It is also not visible in other device wifi list.